# Boundedness and Strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

$f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^2(0,1)$,
$\{ f,f_1,f_2,\ldots \}\subset H^1(0,1)$,
$||f_n||_{H^1(0,1)}\leq M,\ \forall n\geq 1 $,
Is is true that $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $H^1(0,1)$? If not, then what is a counterexample?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: I feel that this is not true. However, I tried proving it also. Simple Cauchy-Schwartz does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the "double subsequence trick"?

Hint: if we do not have $f_n\rightharpoonup f$, then there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converging weakly in $H^1$ to some function $g \ne f$.  (Use Alaoglu.) We still have $f_{n_k} \to f$ in $L^2$.  Now show that this leads to a contradiction.  It will help to consider a linear functional on $H^1$ which takes different values on $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Nate Eldredge.